# google apps script HTMLService button click opens new blank tab

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Fairly new to HTML Service in apps script, have written a very basic UI.

The problem is that when the button is clicked (no onclick handler set) it opens up a new blank tab (I'm using Chrome).

Code below reproduces the behaviour, I have jquery / jquery UI references which are used in the broader project so left them in here.

How do I stop this blank tab opening on button click?  Not shown here but it also happens when entered hit in a text box.

code.js:

```
    function NewProposal() {  
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.show(html.evaluate().setHeight(530).setWidth(1100).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME));
}
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<base target="_top">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.4.1/jsgrid.min.js"></script>


<form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="Create">Create</button>
                </td>                
            </tr>
       </table>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to either get rid of the button, and use something else, or get rid of the form tags, and use div tags.  If you get rid of the form tags, then it's more difficult to collect data from any input tags in the form.  But, I don't see any input tags in your form.  If you have no input tags in your form, then using form tags is pointless.  Maybe you just left them out for purposes of reproducing the error in as little code as possible.

When a button is clicked inside of a form tag, the default behavior is for the current window to issue a POST request.  That refreshes the content in the browser, but if there is no callback to display some other content, the page will go blank.

The only way to avoid this built-in feature of a form with a button, is to not use a button, or not use the form tags.

A click event can be added to multiple different types of HTML elements.  Like a link  `<a>` tags.   Or a `<div>`.  So, you can use something else other than a button, style it to look like a button if you wish, and add a click event to whatever you decide to use.

If you have lots of different types of input tags, it may be better to continue to use the form.  But if you can easily get all the data out of the table some other way, you don't really need the form.  The form adds nothing to the capability of styling or layout.  So, if the benefit of using the form doesn't fit your circumstance, then you can look at other options.

If you want to give feedback to the user about what inputs are required, that's another issue.  The form tags, the required attribute, and the button submission are all part of a system to try to make form submission more automatic, and make data validation and data collection easier.  But, in order to use that "built-in" functionality, it all needs to work together in a certain way.  As with anything that people try to make generic, it's very difficult to make it fit all circumstances.  If you don't want the page to go blank when the button is clicked, all of that built-in behavior can become more of a detriment than a help.

When Apps Script gets the form, it strips out most of the content from the form element, and creates an object of input names and their values.  So, when the "form" object (No longer a real form object) gets to the server, the only way you can get the values out of the object is by using the name attributes.

Comment: thank you!  Your answer prompted some further digging and I eventually found info from google on this ([link](developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) regarding preventing forms from submitting...not sure of this is good practice or not but it has solved the issue.  Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Add ***onsubmit="return(false)"*** inside your form openning tag:

```
<form onsubmit="return(false)">
  ...
</form>
```